# How to print string without ASCII characters in python?

Tags: python, django

I have the following string:

```
teststring= "&sect"
```

When I print it in python within Django I keep getting a weird symbol. How do I make it so that it eliminates the conversion of a string to ASCII symbol and treats it as the literal string "&sect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is interpreting the `&sect` value as `&sect;`, the section character: §

You need to escape the ampersand as `&amp;sect` to prevent this:

```
teststring = "&amp;sect"
```

Django templates can do this escaping for you by using the [escape filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#escape), or you can use the [`cgi.escape()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape):

```
teststring = cgi.escape("&sect")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use django's [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escape) filter in your template. Something like:

```
<b>check out my string: {{ teststring|escape }}</b>
```

Or turn [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape) on.